# Call a method from UIButton subclass @implementation

Tags: iphone, ios4, call

I work on a project for iPhone iOS 4 with Xcode 4.

I have subclassed a UIButton so that it intercepts single and double tap.

This is the final part of @implementation of the UIButton subclass, two instance methods where the taps are "recorded";

```
 - (void) handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
     NSLog(@"single tap");
 }

 - (void) handleDoubleTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
     NSLog(@"double tap");
 }
```

A button instance is created in nib and all works OK: it intercepts single tap and double tap and output the NSLog.

Now the question: I have in my ViewController two methods (resetAllFields and populateAllFields) and I need that single tap execute resetAllFields and double tap execute populateAllFields.

How can I do? Where do I put the call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle the behavior in the ViewController the typical solution is to add a `@protocol` in your custom button class that defines methods for handling the single and double taps.

i.e. in your CustomButton.h

```
@protocol CustomButtonDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)button:(CustomButton *)button tappedWithCount:(int)count;
@end
```

You then have a delegate that implements this protocol in your custom button class and call those methods on the delegate when your taps are detected.

i.e. in your CustomButton.h

```
id <CustomButtonDelegate> _delegate;
```

in your methods in the implementation:

```
- (void) handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
   NSLog(@"single tap");
   [self.delegate button:self tappedWithCount:1];
}

- (void) handleDoubleTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
   NSLog(@"double tap");
   [self.delegate button:self tappedWithCount:2];
}
```

Your View Controller than implements the protocol methods and sets itself as the custom button's delegate.

ie. in your ViewControllers implementation

```
- (void)button:(CustomButton *)button tappedWithCount:(int)count {
     if (count == 1) {
         [self resetAllFields];
     } else if (count == 2) {
         [self populateAllFields];
     }
}
```

Since you are using Interface Builder to set the custom button you can assign your view controller as a delegate in there or in the ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Thank you. I am a newbie, so I need more explanation about delegate. How can I create them?

Comment: Oops, now I see your full answer. Thank you.

Comment: How can i declare the delegate in viewDidLoad? i tried [CustomButton setDelegate:self]; but get warning CustomButton may not respond to setDelegate

Comment: that button was set in interface builder correct? If so, then you can obtain it via the outlet. That is, self.customButton.delegate = self

Comment: Also, make sure you set up a @property for the delegate.

Comment: Where do I put this? self.customButton._delegate = self

Comment: In ViewController > viewDidLoad get a warning assign to id<customButtonDelegate> from incompatible type ViewController

Comment: Your view controller should declare that it is a CustomButtonDelegate in the interface: @interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CustomButtonDelegate>